# checking age of a person, the person has date of birth stored as a date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
select
    //
from
    //
where
    //this is the place i need help with
```

I have a table `person` with column `dob date`.
I want to be able to select rows of people aged 1 or more.

some mock date:

```
name       dob
```

```
person 1   13-DEC-2014
person 2   24-JAN-2011
person 3   05-MAY-2013
person 4   17-APR-2014
person 5   21-DEC-2013
person 6   11-NOV-2014
```

in this scenario i would expect the names 'person 2', 'person 3' and 'person 5' to be listed in the output. i know how to do the select and from statement in my scenario, just not a where. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ADD_MONTHS()`:

```
SELECT * FROM person
 WHERE dob <= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12));
```

In the above I'm actually adding -12 months (or 1 year -- equivalent to subtracting 12 months) to the value of `SYSDATE`.

Comment: a couple of these answers where just what i needed, yours was perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from person
 where dob <= add_months( trunc(sysdate), -12 )
```

will return everyone whose birth date is more than 12 months before the current date.  `sysdate` returns the current date and time.  `trunc` removes the time component (setting it to midnight).  Then `add_months` subtracts 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the threshold and compare dob to that:

```
where dob <= add_months(sysdate, -12))
```

Using a constant expression for the threshold would also mean that if an index existed on dob then it would be a candidate for usage. Even if an index didn't exist, it would still be much more efficient than ccukating a date from (every value of) dob and comparing it to today.

Comment: select
        p.name
    from
        person p
    where
        p.dob <= subdate(current_date, interval 1 year) - this is the query im getting error with.

Comment: `SUBDATE()` is a MySQL function, not Oracle.

Comment: In addition, `INTERVAL`s in Oracle are not leap year safe in accordance with the ANSI standard. So if `CURRENT_DATE` is February 29, 2016, for example, the above would break.

Answer (score -2):

to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') - to_char(dob,'YYYY')>1

Comment: This will return people born in earlier years, not those who are a year older or more.

Comment: You have to use >=  instead of >

Comment: It still isn't right ... for example, it would return anyone born in 2014 even if they're not yet 1 year old.